# Problems opening Google Play Market Link on specific devices from android application

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I have a basic android application and have added an item to my settings menu to provide users a link to my app on the play store so that they can rate it easily.

I have got code that works on all my devices (Samsung Galaxy S3, Google Nexus 7 (2012), HTC One), however a friends Samsung Galaxy S2 does nothing when the settings item is clicked.

See code below, thanks in advance.

---

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean rateApp (MenuItem item) { 
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=manning.luke.glutenfreeingredients"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
    return false;
}
```

Settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:title="@string/rateApp"
        android:onClick="rateApp" >
    </item>    
</menu>
```

Comment: What version of Android is your friend's S2 running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Menu Resource guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html), `android:onClick` was only added in API Level 11 (Honeycomb) - older versions of Android will ignore this attribute.

Typically, you instead have a menu definition like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/rateApp" 
        android:title="@string/rateApp">
    </item>    
</menu>
```

And then use `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.rateApp:
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                "market://details?id=manning.luke.glutenfreeingredients"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```